# How to check if server socket is close in UDP

Tags: c++, winsock

I am making a UPD socket application based on winsock. However, I cant figure out how to check if server socket is closed or not. I try to use recvfrom but it still return sent data even when the program closed. Is there anyway to check if a socket is closed or not.

Comment: Keep track of it yourself inside the program? Keep a list of sockets that are open, and only use sockets from this list for your communication. Once you close a socket, remove it from the list.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your issue. How can recvfrom return data when the program is closed? What program? It's a weird statement. Anyway, are you asking how to detect whether a remote peer is still "connected" over UDP? This is typically done via manual connections tracking and timeouts.

Comment: Can you be more specific. How to do that. Sorry if any convenience but I am new to socket programming. P/s: by program close I mean the server is closed but the client still receive sent data.

Comment: Most socket communication includes buffers on multiple levels. A program sending data might have closed the sockets, but the data in the buffers might not yet have been transmitted. Or the receiving end might not have read the received data from the buffers on that side.

Comment: When a machine goes down, data it has already sent is not magically removed from the netowrk before anyone has a chance to receive it. Also, UDP is a connectionless packet-oriented protocol. If you want to know if and when the other end is "up", you need to implement your own protocol for doing that on top of UDP.